# How to check in Docker whether a volume exists and is not empty and run different docker-compose.yml depending on this?

Tags: docker, if-statement, docker-compose, persistent-volumes, volumes

I'm deploying an application with a Dockerfile and docker-compose. It loads a model from an AWS bucket to run the application. When the containers get restarted (not intentionally but because of the cloud provider), it loads again the model from AWS. What I would like to achive is storing the model on a persistent volume. In case of a restart, I would like to check whether the volume exists and is not empty and if so run a different docker-compose file which has a different bash command, not loading the model from AWS again.

This is part of my docker-compose.yml:

```
  rasa-server:
    image: rasa-bot:latest
    working_dir: /app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
     - ./models /app/models

    command: bash -c "rasa run --model model.tar.gz --remote-storage aws --endpoints endpoints.yml --credentials credentials.yml --enable-api --cors \"*\" --debug --port 5006"
```

In case of a restart the command would look like this:

```
    command: bash -c "rasa run --model model.tar.gz --endpoints endpoints.yml --credentials credentials.yml --enable-api --cors \"*\" --debug --port 5006"
```

Note that this

> --remote-storage aws

was removed.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.7-stretch AS BASE

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get --assume-yes --no-install-recommends install \
        build-essential \
        curl \
        git \
        jq \
        libgomp1 \
        vim

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip

RUN pip install rasa==3.1
RUN pip3 install boto3

ADD . .
```

I know that I can use this:

```
docker volume ls
```

to list volumes. But I do not know how to wrap this in a if condition to check whether

```
     - ./models /app/models
```

exists and is not empty and if it is not empty run a second docker-compose.yml which contains the second modified bash command.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an if statement in your bash command to use AWS or not depending on the result you get from `docker volume ls`
using `-f name=` you can filter based on the volume name and then you can check if it's not null and run a different command.

Note that this command is just an example and I have no idea if it works or not as I don't use bash everyday.

```
command: bash -c "
    VOLUME = docker volume ls -f name=FOO
    if [ -z "$VOLUME" ]; 
    then
        rasa run --model model.tar.gz --remote-storage aws --endpoints endpoints.yml --credentials credentials.yml --enable-api --cors \"*\" --debug --port 5006
    else 
        rasa run --model model.tar.gz --endpoints endpoints.yml --credentials credentials.yml --enable-api --cors \"*\" --debug --port 5006
    fi
    "
```

Answer (score 1):

I would accomplish this by making the main container command actually be a script that looks to see if the file exists and optionally fills in the command line argument.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

MODEL_EXISTS=$(test -f /app/models/model.tar.gz && echo yes)

exec rasa run \
  --model model.tar.gz \
  ${MODEL_EXISTS:---remote-storage aws} \
  --endpoints endpoints.yml \
  ...
```

The first line uses the **test**(1) shell command to see if the file already exists, and sets the variable `MODEL_EXISTS` to `yes` if it exists and empty if it does not.  Then in the command, there is a shell parameter expansion: if the variable `MODEL_EXISTS` is unset or empty `:-` then expand and split the text `--remote-storage aws`.  (This approach inspired by [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).)

In your Dockerfile, `COPY` this script into your image and make it be the default `CMD`.  It needs to be executable like any other script (run `chmod +x` on your host and commit that change to source control); since it is executable and begins with a "shebang" line, you do not need to explicitly name the shell when you run it.

```bash
...
COPY rasa-run ./
CMD ["./rasa-run"]
```

In your Compose file, you do not need to override the `command:`, change the `working_dir:` from what the Dockerfile sets, or change from a couple of Compose-provided defaults.  You should be able to reduce this to

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  rasa-server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./models:/app/models
```

More generally for this class of question, I might suggest:

1. Prefer setting a Dockerfile default `CMD` to a Compose `command:` override; and
2. Write out non-trivial logic in a script and run that script as the main container command; don't write complicated conditionals in an inline `CMD` or `command:`.

Comment: Thank you @David! Would you mind explaining to me where I need to write the script and with which file extension or would it be directly in the Dockerfile? And when I cannot run chmod +x how can I make it executable otherwise?

Comment: When the Dockerfile `COPY rasa-run .`, the `rasa-run` is that script.  It doesn't particularly need an extension.  chmod(1) is a core Unix command and your host MacOS or Linux system will definitely be able to run it.